# Getting a specialised collection of objects from a base collection

Tags: c#, collections

Say I have a collection of animals in c# which contains dogs, cats, etc ... how can I get all the items in the base collection that are dogs so I can perform other operations on all the dog items as if they were in their own separate collection, as if they were in a `List<Dog>` (and so that the objects are also updated in the base collection) ?

For code answers, assume `List<Animals>` is a sufficient as I want to avoid [implementing my own generic collection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21241/Implementing-C-Generic-Collections-using-ICollecti) if possible.

EDIT: I've just noticed this question is very similar to [c# collection inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360516/c-sharp-collection-inheritance?rq=1)

Comment: Looks like that question covers it, any reason you can't use `OfType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a base method in base class, like

```
public class Base {

    List<Animals> animals = .... 
    ...
    ....

    public IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenOfType<T>()  
        where T : Animals
    {
       return animals.OfType<T>();  // using System.Linq;
    }
}
```

Something like that. You should naturally change this to fit your exact needs.

Comment: That won't compile. I guess you meant `public IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenOfType<T>() { return animals.OfType<T>(); }`. And where is that base class coming from?

Comment: You corrected only one of the three errors.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: OP's talks about some base class (may be Animal) may be something else. In *my* code it's just a concept.

Comment: Yeh, it's the right idea but needs editing to be correct before an accept. For example, the `List<Animals>` could be anywhere except the base class (e.g. `Program`) but `Base` should clearly be `Animals`.

Comment: @Izzy: I have no idea how your code structured inside application, I presented just a *concept*, an *idea*, you need to fit this in your application and apply changes if need.

Comment: I understand (hence why I +1'd), but for people that don't know my code and seeing this question it could be in better context. EDIT: And to be fair, `T` is a `Type` and is being used like a variable in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to other posters, and using OfType, you could do;

```
List<Dog> dogList = new List<Dog>();

foreach(Animal a in animals.OfType<Dog>())
    {
      //Do stuff with your dogs here, for example;
      dogList.Add(a);
    }
```

Now you've got all of your dogs in a seperate list, or whatever you want to do with them. The dogs will also still exist in your base collection too.

Comment: parens after OfType are missing. And whats the reason not to use `List<Dog> dogList = animals.OfType<Dog>().ToList()`?

Comment: Sorry, free-typed. And you could do that too. I guess this way allows you to do other stuff with the dog too, if you wanted more than to add to another list. But fair point.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Dog> dogList = new List<Dog>();
foreach(Animal a in animals) { //animals is your animal list
   if(a.GetType() == typeof(Dog)) { //check if the current Animal (a) is a dog
      dogList.Add(a as Dog); //add the dog to the dogList
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `OfType`?

Comment: sure, you can use OfType if you want but I never used it so I use typeof() and GetType().

Comment: this does not work for `class SpecialDog : Dog` and null references will throw while OfType<Dog>() does handle both well

Comment: I try to shy away from [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) as much as possible